# Testing ViewPager with multiple fragments using android espresso

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-espresso

I am trying to test my app which uses `ViewPager`. Each page contains fragments but these fragments are not always visible. I want to check visibility of a fragment in the currently visible page.

```
onView(withId(R.id.container_weather))
    .check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));
```

But  the problem is that espresso looks are all the pages not just the current page and I get the following error:

> android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: 'with id: eu.airpatrol.android:id/container_weather' matches multiple views in the hierarchy...

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem, however using the condition `isCompletelyDisplayed()` solved this problem as it only takes into account the on-screen views.

So, something like this should work:

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id.container_weather), isCompletelyDisplayed()))
.check(matches(withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE)));
```

Note: `isDisplayed()` works too in some cases but it also takes views off-screen into account and won't work if the ViewPager has any other page pr fragment loaded with the same view id.

Answer (score 6):

Your tests are failing because of multiple elements with the same id. You can combine conditions using `allOf(...)`. Then use `isDisplayed()` to check that matched view is visible on the screen. Below example can work:

```
onView(allOf(
    withEffectiveVisibility(ViewMatchers.Visibility.VISIBLE),
    withId(R.id.container_weather)))
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried your solution but it still has the same problem. I have two pages and both contain this fragment and for some reason both have visibility=VISIBLE in the View Hierarchy.

Comment: Do you have some unique text or child element inside R.id.container_weather? If yes you can add this check also inside `allOf()`.

Comment: The only difference between the two is the y-coordinate because the two are on different pages. :(

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ? I am stuck with the same issue. In  my case both the fragments are exactly identical with only then data shown by them being the only difference

Comment: Using `allOf()` fixed the problem for me (thanks) but note that most likely you'll want to be matching on `isDisplayed()` or `isCompletelyDisplayed()` and not `withEffectiveVisibility()` because the latter method matches on the `visibility` property of the `View` and not on whether it's actually visible on the screen.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this exact same problem. I was fortunate because the view hierarchies in my `ViewPager` can be easily identified by their siblings, so I was able to solve this using the `hasSibling` matcher, like so:

```java
onView(
    allOf(
        hasSibling(withId(R.id.some_sibling)),
        withId(R.id.field_to_test)
    )
).perform(replaceText("123"));
```

Not a perfect solution as it can be slightly brittle, but in my case I think it was an acceptable compromise.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, where I was reusing the button layout and it was giving me a matches multiple views in the hierarchy exception.

So the easy work around I did was to create 2 different screens and have 2 different methods with different text.

1. Withdraw Screen:

   ```
   public WithdrawScreen clickWithdraw() {
       onView(allOf(withId(R.id.save_button), withText("Withdraw")))
           .perform(click());
       return this; 
   }
   ```
2. Deposit Screen:

   ```
   public DepositScreen clickDeposit() {
       onView(allOf(withId(R.id.save_button), withText("Deposit")))
           .perform(click());
       return this;
   }
   ```

and in my tests, I create a new instance of both screens and call the above methods based on screen reference which is a bit easy to test for.

```
WithdrawScreen withdrawInstance = new WithdrawScreen();
withdrawInstance.clickWithdraw();

DepositScreen depositInstance = new DepositScreen();
depositInstance.clickDeposit();
```

The point was they were using same id - R.id.save_button for button and I was replacing text of button based on visibility of the fragment we are on.

Hope it helps.